# CSS Hover/Slider Changes

Tags: css

I am fairly newbie so bear with me if this seems simple to you, because it isn't simple to me!

I've bought a nice [template](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39062.html) which is providing the framework for a new food festival site I'm building.  I'm new here, so they won't even let me post a screenshot, so I can't show you how I've modified the template!  Dumb!

Below the main logo are several hover buttons which slide an image from right to left.  I'd like to turn them into hover images which don't 'slide' but simply change on mouseover - as suggested in [this article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/pure-css-image-hover/).

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you can post a link to a screenshot?

Comment: what you should do Robert is make us of icon fonts, they allow for complete color changing effects and are faster to load if you are using multiple icons/images because all the icons can be loaded through one font file instead of 6-7 http requests for large images. The icons from an icon font can be changed in many ways, including color hovering effects. I can make you a demo if you'd like and give you some valuable resources.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add in your CSS:

```
ul#menu:hover li{
  background-image: url('yourImageUrl');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

eventually using `opacity` to make the hover image semi-transparent, and adjusting the margin / padding according to your layout

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSGDH/

Answer (score 0):

I think that I finally know your problem, and it lies in the fact that the "mouse hover effect" that we are seeing is actually triggered by a javascript and **not** the CSS3 which was presumed.

And in order to get what you want, you should **first** disable the javascript which is overriding the css rules. and its location is "http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_39062/js/jquery.backgroundpos.js"

Once the js/ is disabled then you can easily implement your idea using the css3 trick that you linked to. You can further inquire about how to implement that, but for the time being I suppose that you'd like to do it yourself.